# Is the system limiting my memory?

Tags: memory, cgroups

I am running some code on a shared remote machine. When running several instances in parallel, they relatively quickly die with `std::bad_alloc`, while a single instance runs much longer (in any case, 1 thread per instance). This made me wonder if I may only use a fixed amount of memory as a user. Of course, this makes sense. Is there any way to find out if this is the case (besides asking the admin)?

Edit: The output of `ulimit -a` is

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       2063129
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  66029704
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 2063129
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

Comment: Edit your question and add `ulimit -a`

Comment: Instrument the code / capture the errors

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Done.

Comment: Have you measured the peak memory consumption of each instance of your code and compared it with the machine's total memory?  Could it be that your code consumes a large enough percentage of the machine's memory that only a few instances will fit in the shared machine (or perhaps only one)?

Comment: @SottoVoce The program dies usually below 10 GB. The system has 500 GB of RAM, of which only a small fraction is used usually.

Comment: However, when I run a single instance, it does not die. This is why I assume there is some limit for the total amount of memory I can use for all processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that with software that reserved (but never actually used) huge amounts of memory.

I found 2 solutions for that:

- Over-commit memory. You can ask the Linux kernel to say "sure there is more memory" even if there really isn't. (/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 1)
- Add swap. Over-committing memory has bitten me a few times, where debugging this was really hard, so today I prefer simply to add more swap. If the system goes into thrashing and becomes slow as a dog, I at least know the cause.